# Need help walking through nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

Pardon my ignorance, I'm new to Ruby, but not programming. I'm using a gem called Ancestry to store hierarchical data in my application. They have a method called "descendants" that returns a nested hash of all the descending children, grandchildren, etc.. in a node, but I'm having a hard time trying to loop through each node and output all the child nodes.

Here's what the data structure looks like

```
{
  #<Forum id: 16, name: "Parent 1", ancestry: "7", display_order: 1> =>{}, 
  #<Forum id: 17, name: "Parent 2", ancestry: "7", display_order: 2> =>{}, 
  #<Forum id: 13, name: "Parent 3", ancestry: "7", display_order: 3> =>
  {
    #<Forum id: 14, name: "Child 1", ancestry: "7/13", display_order: 1> =>{}, 
    #<Forum id: 15, name: "Child 2", ancestry: "7/13", display_order: 2> =>
    {
      #<Forum id: 18, name: "Grand Child", ancestry: "7/13/15", display_order: 1> =>{}, 
    }
  }
}
```

When I loop through that data using the code below, the parent nodes are the only ones that end up being rendered to the screen.

```
<% forum.descendants.arrange(:order => :display_order).map do |forum,key| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'forum', :locals => {:forum => forum} %>
<% end %>
```

How can I render the child nodes as well? I know they're accessible through the "key" variable, but I don't know how to tell when the "key" variable has data that I can render and how to output that data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the key is a hash by doing `key.is_a?(Hash)`.

In your example, it will always evaluate to true because `{}` is an empty hash. You can check whether the hash is empty with `key.empty?`

To iterate through the nested hash, you can do it recursively something like this

```
def display hash
    hash.each do |key, val|
        # print key etc
        if val.is_a?(Hash)
            display val
        else
            # print value or whatever operation you want
        end
    end
end
```